# Show that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not quasi isometric to the $3-$regular tree $T_3$

Tags: graph-theory, geometric-group-theory

To do this I would try by contradiction, assume there is a q.i $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\to T_3$ and map some sufficiently large set and show that the image cannot actually be cobounded. I don't really have any idea how to actually do this in practice or evem if this is the best way to do this.

Comment: A good first step is to mess around with triangles and what $\phi$ (or a coarse inverse) would do with it

Comment: Actually 1) there's no coarse embedding from $\mathbf{R}^2$ to $T_3$, but neither using ends nor growth works directly. Asymptotic dimension works in this case, and maybe a more pedestrian approach. 2) There's no coarse embedding from $T_3$ to $\mathbf{R}^2$, using growth.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to pick the correct quasi-isometry invariant. In this case, use ends. In brief, for proper geodesic metric spaces, the set of ends is a quasi-isometry invariant, in the following sense:

> Theorem: If $X,Y$ are proper geodesic metric spaces and if $f:X \to Y$ is a quasi-isometry then $f$ induces a bijection from the ends of $X$ to the ends of $Y$.

Since $\mathbb{R}^2$ has one end and $T_3$ has infinitely many ends, there is no bijection between their ends, so there is no quasi-isometry between them.

Comment: The best way to do this is to pick the correct quasi-isometry invariant. In this case, use the growth of balls in these two spaces.

Comment: @Did: Using growth works just as well. But there is an implication behind your comment that I cannot unravel. Certainly you don't mean that there is something wrong with using ends? Or are you just pointing out that there's more than one quasi-isometry invariant to use?

Comment: The latter. $ $